# c++ overloading operator << why & needed?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, ostream

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& cout, const Complex& num) {
    std::cout << num.a << "+i" << num.b;
    return std::cout;
}
```

When I overload `<<` operator, why do I have to code & next to `ostream`?

Comment: Look to your c++ book/online resources and read about what a reference is.

Comment: You've got an error on the second line; that should be `cout` without the `std::`.

Comment: I know what reference is... I don't know why it's necessary in this context

Comment: @SunHyuckHwang. No, you need to remove `std::` of both of them. See my answer below, though your second version is better than the first, if you use `std::cout` as the only ostream object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because

## for return type:

- `ostream` objects are not copyable, so they cannot be used as the return type unless you perform `move` operation.

## for parameter:

- `ostream` objects are not copyable, so they cannot be used as the parameter's type unless you perform `move` operation.
- It's expected that `operator <<` may change the state of the parameter, so we should pass by reference.

And considering the second principle for parameter, your code should be corrected to:

```cpp
ostream& operator<<(ostream& cout, const Complex& num) {
    cout << num.a << "+i" << num.b;
    return cout;
}
```

Comment: so in c++ & is used as reference, and move operator?

Comment: @SunHyuckHwang No, I mean if you don't use `std::ostream&`, you need to perform move operation when calling the operator function. For example, `std::cout << Complex();` will generate compile error if you use `std::ostream` instead of `std::ostream&`

Comment: @SunHyuckHwang Plus, in that case you cannot simply `return cout`, you need to write `return std::move(std::cout)`, very odd, isn't it? And after `move` your `std::cout` become unusable, so simply don't use it. I introduce this only to make my answer more pricise.